# Magento 2 - Class not found

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I always get this error if I try to load my site, even though the class does exist.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Company\\App\\Observer\\Frontend\\Controller\\ActionPredispatch'
```

**app/code/Company/App/etc/frontend/events.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_predispatch">
        <observer name="company_app_observer_frontend_controller_actionpredispatch_controller_action_predispatch"
                  instance="Company\App\Observer\Frontend\Controller\ActionPredispatch"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

**app/code/Company/App/Observer/Frontend/Controller/ActionPredispatch.php:**

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Company\App\Observer\Frontend\Controller;
    
class ActionPredispatch implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    ...
}
```

---

I tried this:

```
rm -rf generated/*
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

But I still get the error.

The module is enabled of course.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a controller execute method related error.So please check your controller execute method like this or not.

public function execute(**\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer**)
{

.....     
}

Comment: It already is like this.

Comment: Please change observer name and check might be name related issue.

Comment: I already found the solution. https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/363646/66769

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this was a hard one!

The problem was caused by the file app/code/Company/App/Observer/Frontend/Controller/ActionPredispatch.php, because it had whitespace in the name  `ActionPredispatch.php`.

After I removed the whitespace it works!